# Is it legal to castle by tipping the rook with the king?

Tags: rules, castling

Nakamura castles with two hands. But I saw one of my students taking their king and "tipping" their rook towards f1.

Is this USCF/FIDE legal?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the word "tipping"?

Comment: @konsolas: "cause (an object) to move somewhere by striking or touching it lightly."

Answer (score 4):

> Nakamura castles with two hands.

That's actually illegal:

> 4.1 Each move must be played with one hand only.

---

As for your student, there's no rule that you are not allowed to simultaneously move two pieces at once, and since [the rules](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=208&view=article) do not describe exactly *how* the king and rook reach their final squares, this is up to the player. In any case, this is *not* a violation of rule 4.4.2:

> 4.4.2 [If a player having the move:] deliberately touches a rook and then his king he is not allowed to castle on that side on that move and the situation shall be governed by Article 4.3.1
>
> 4.3.1 one or more of his own pieces, he must move the first piece touched that can be moved